# Send email with image from server-side

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code in C#, who is called from ASP.NET page using an ScriptManager:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void testEmail(string FileName)
    {
        //Asigning a hardcoded value for test
        FileName="c:\\Users\\myuser\\Pictures\\mypicture.jpg";
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        message.From = new MailAddress("originemailaddr@serverx.net");
        message.To.Add("detinationmail@servery.net");
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, "text/plain");
        AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("Here is an embedded image.<img src=cid:companylogo>", null, "text/html");
        LinkedResource logo = new LinkedResource(FileName, "image/jpg");
        logo.ContentId = "companylogo";
        htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

        message.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
        message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("0.0.0.0", 25);
        client.Timeout = 1000;
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        client.Send(message);

        message.Dispose();
        client.Dispose();
    }
```

The code works ok when I debug on my local machine. Once is published, returns an 500 error (I think is due the code is trying to locate the file on the server, not in the local computer who is opening the webpage). I have some time trying to find information, but with no luck so far. Any advice?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5385714/revisions) to find the actual .NET exception and source behind the generic 500 error.

Comment: you should have image file on the server. and locate it by Server.MapPath()

Comment: @yogi970 doesn't exist a way to read a image file located at client side?

Comment: use file upload tool by that you can get the file easily

Comment: by directly hard code the local path is not a good idea!

Comment: @yogi970 in this case I hardcoded the path just for test purposes. Do you have the link to a sample for a upload tool? Thanks!